# Getting weird errors and dont know how to fix

Tags: java

Trying to make a bunch of methods and print out their results. I thought what I have is fine but I'm getting weird errors that I don't know what they mean.
I even cant get a simple "test" to print out for some reason

I have written out the methods but i havent called for them yet bc I cant even get it to work without terminating.

```
System.out.print("Test");
public static double pow(double a, double b){
    return Math.pow(a, b);
} //Use 3.0 and 2.0

public static double sqrt(double x) {
    return Math.sqrt(x);
} //25.0

public static int max(int a, int b) {
    if ( a < b ) {return b;}
    else {return a;}
} //Use 6 and 2

public static double max(double a, double b) {
    if ( a < b ) {return b;}
    else {return a;}
} //Use -50.0 and 7.0

public static double random() {
    return Math.random();
}
```

I would like at least to get to print the test word. Also for the methods to work when called.

Comment: java != javascript. Updated from tag javascript to java

Comment: What errors are you getting? Seems you have a method invocation statement in the body of the class. This is incorrect.

Comment: How are you calling these methods?